# Azure EventGrid: Webhook validation callback receives InternalServerError when stale

Tags: azure-eventgrid

#### Internal Server Error with stale validations

Given the following:

- I have specified `Cloud Event Schema 1.0` for a subscription to a Domain Topic.
- I have acknowledged the validation OPTIONS request with a 200 response containing no headers. This is in order to use a manual callback with the URL contained in the `WebHook-Request-Callback` header.
- The subscription, as expected, then reports a `provisioningState` of `AwaitingManualAction`
- After approximately 10 minutes the subscription silently disappears.

When I then make a request to the validation endpoint it fails with:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "The operation failed due to an internal server error. The initial state of the impacted resources (if any) are restored. Please try again in few minutes. If error still persists, report <guid>:<MM/d/yyyy h:mm:dd aa> (UTC) to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket ."
    }
}
```

Note that using an invalid URL (such as manipulating the GUID) results in a 400 error, and revalidating an already validated subscription is a 2xx.

Clearly we need to validate promptly to activate the subscription - I have no issue with that; but occasionally unavoidable delays happen and we need to handle them cleanly. Also, whilst we know we can immediately respond with headers to validate, sometimes we want to go the callback route.

This 500 response seems like a quite specific bug to me. I can understand EventGrid not wanting to track a subscription awaiting validation forever - but a 404 would surely be a better response here than a 500?

#### Poor Documentation

The behaviour of unvalidated subscriptions disappearing after 10 minutes is not specified in the [Cloud Event Standard](https://github.com/cloudevents/spec/blob/v1.0/http-webhook.md#4-abuse-protection); clearly this is an Azure Event Grid decision.

However, [Event Grid's own documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery#endpoint-validation-with-cloudevents-v10) is vague and could be improved. [Asynchronous validation under the `Event Grid Schema`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery#endpoint-validation-with-event-grid-events) by contrast is specified as having a 5 minute timeout and then transitioning to a `provisioningStatus` of failed. It's weird that `Cloud Event Schema` subscriptions just disappear - why not have the same behaviour? It would provide a better user experience.

I appreciate this is more of a bug-report than a question; but it felt useful to share. :)